# Code sample for table_class_list, table_row_class_list

Tags: css, tinymce-4

I am looking forward to use the latest version of TinyMCE plugin with all new good features. I tried with the following URL : https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/table/ to see how the table plugin works.

In  the following sample  I see that  there are couple of classes called Dog and Cat with values dog and cat.

Can anyone help me to know where the classes should be defined.

Any code sample will help me.

table_class_list :

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "table",
  menubar: "table",
  toolbar: "table",
  table_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
    {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
  ]
});
```

I tried to add few css  which is part of www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css, but I am not seeing any changes.

Any help on this with some code sample will help me a lot.

body {
padding: 5px;

}

cat{
background-color:red;
}

dog{
background-color:green;
}

Comment: Are you asking where to put the CSS classes? Because if you are, they can go anywhere as long as they're included on the same page

Answer (score 0):

if you add 'table_class_list', that means you can see those class list in dialog. Right click on the table and open table properties, then you select it and apply it.

As per design, **This option enables you to specify a list of classes to present in the table options dialog box**

Thanks.